# Bind custom domain to azure API management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

we have an APIM and we also own a custom domain that was procured from azure domain.
how to actually bind this custom domain to the api manager ?

from my experience in configuring vps, usually we bind the cname, etc in the server and bind the vps ns in the domain configuration.

anyone know to bind this custom domain so it can be used by the azure API management (we already have the certificate, pfx, etc)..

expectation :

before
https://sample.developer.azure-api.net

into
https://sample.com

Comment: iirc,  Azure has AzureDNS that you can use to accomplish that though I've only looked at it for private dns functionality though.

Comment: Have you looked in the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain

Comment: Important is - assuming you want to have TLS/HTTPS - that you also create a certificate with a SN matching the FQDN/domain name. Then it is really not so complicated and works according to docs.